# Is the Legendary Super Saiyan (green) transformation limitless in power?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-movies

So now that both Broly, and Kale, who has a transformation which looks exactly like Broly's, have been quoting saying both the same "My Ki is building... Overflowing..." and that Kyabe tells Kale "stop gathering ki!", this topic comes to talk again. Is Broly and now Kale legendary super saiyan transformation limitless in power? This has been talked before with Broly's movies, but the last episode of Dragon Ball Super brings new information to the topic. What about the other canon sources like the Daizenshuu, does it say something about it?

Comment: Honestly, even in Z these things were unclear but now in Super i would say it can be if it suits the storyline. Power balance has been through the roof so i would say, yeah the power of a LSSY could be "limitless"

Comment: Now that I think about it, since Battle of gods most character transformations are portrayed as being limitless, arent they? Vegita when Beerus slapped Bulma, Gohan is always being kinda limitless, Trunks when he made the Galick-ho againt fused Zamasu, Goku when he made the kamehameha against fused Zamasu. But they still have fixed multipliers for the SSJ, SSJ2 and SSJ3 (not for SSG, SS Blue and SS Rage which are unknown if they exist)

Comment: Yeah but every form is basically "limitless"  . As you get stronger all your transformations get more potent as well. I know you are referring in the current time but Super went all over the place, and the growth level is insane for each character. I mean roshi was surpassed by goku almost at the first budokai in the original dragonball and now suddenly he can hold his own against current goku, I think "power" is a concept that mostly does not apply in Super, since there are too many anomalies

Comment: In Dragon Ball Z, except Gohan who had rage attacks, the other characters could rise his powers but only with training. But now in Dragon Ball Super, also Vegita, Trunks and Goku have rage attacks who surpass their limits in the moment

Comment: *I meant with training or with zenkai boosts

Comment: yeah its a super thing... nothing more to say i guess

Comment: When Caulifa becomes SSJ for first time she also says "My Ki is building... Overflowing...".. so i guess they will be comparing to their base forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems entirely feasible for them to have an unlimited supply of ki. Perhaps while in that transformation, their bodies rapidly generate more and more ki until it just overflows. That however isn't the same thing as having limitless power. Just because you have infinite MP, doesn't mean that you can deal a lot of damage.

To answer your question, I'm not aware of the Daizenshuu mentioning it (nor any official source), but it is clear that the legendary super saiyan transformation is different than the normal transformation. Unlimited ki has appeared in Dragon Ball before too, Androids 17 & 18 were stated to have such an ability. Thus, given the precedence and the dialogue we've seen in regards to the form, I can say with absolute certainty that the answer is "probably".

Comment: ki, energy, power, force are all related in Dragon Ball. The japanese meaning of ki is spirit, the meaning given in Dragon Ball is also energy. The japanese word chikara means energy, power, force, ability, vigor, strenght, might. It's all the same for them.